# How to call WCF service method from POSTMAN

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, postman

I am trying to call a service using WCF endpoint.
The WCF service  is hosted on a Windows Service,

This is the config.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>  
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xmlTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xmlTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xmlTraceListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="C:\logwcf\Service.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" />
  </system.web>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="True">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" 
                        logMalformedMessages="true" 
                        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
          <filters>
            <clear/>
          </filters>
        </messageLogging>
      </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Hostware" closeTimeout="00:10:30" openTimeout="00:10:30" receiveTimeout="00:10:30" sendTimeout="00:10:30" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="xx.ServicioDistribucion.AnalisisDatos.Servicios.CuentasCobrar" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorDistribucion">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Hostware" contract="xx.ServicioDistribucion.AnalisisDatos.Interfaces.ICuentasCobrar">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://xx.143.46.82:8733/xx.ServicioDistribucion.AnalisisDatos.Servicios.CuentasCobrar/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorDistribucion">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000"/>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
<!--<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And we are trying to call the service with POSTMAN like this:

This is the raw body:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:ProcesarListaCuentasCobrarCIA100/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But, we are getting this response

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:DestinationUnreachable</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="es-CO">The message with To 'http://xx.143.46.82:8733/xxServicioDistribucion.AnalisisDatos.Servicios.CuentasCobrar/ProcesarListaCuentasCobrarCIA100/' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Content  type heaer is text/xml.

and we are trying to use a POST

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIRC when you make SOAP calls to a WCF server, there are HTTP headers that have to be set in addition to the body content.

My old SOAP calls have headers of the form:

```
SOAPAction: http://domain/EndPoint
```

You may need to check this. If you have a working client, capture the traffic with Fiddler. Also, I have the content-type set to "text/xml; charset=utf-8" and I seem to recall that some servers are picky about the content-type on POST.

Comment: SOAP UI Headers sample:

`POST http://server/WcfService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IServiceContract/Ping"
Content-Length: 303
Host: server
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)`

Answer (score 40):

1. Run your WCF. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial
   [image]
2. Open wsdl and find Action 
   [image]
3. You can also find Action in WCF test client
   [image]
   [image]
4. In PostMan
   URL - from wsdl - http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService/

Headers -

Content-Type:   text/xml

SOAPAction:     http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Add 
[image]
4. From WCF test Client add body. 
For me body is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <s:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples">
      <n1>1</n1>
      <n2>1</n2>
    </Add>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In dropdown chose - xml
[image]
Send
[image]

Comment: These instructions are good. A couple of mistakes I made:
1. I copied the entire Soap body from WCF Test client, instead of just the body, which gave me a 400.
2. The WCF test client was calling my localhost on port 7321. When I called that from Postman I always got a 404. In the WCF test client I had to open the "Config file", and in there the <endpoint address="https://localhost:44394 has a different port. Once I changed Postman to call on 44394 it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I found the easiest way to get WCF calls working in Postman is as follows...

1.) Open Fiddler and debug your WCF project locally, the Visual Studio WCF Test Client opens.

2.) In the WCF Test Client invoke a call to your service method to get a response.

3.) Click on the request in Fiddler.

4.) Click on the 'RAW' tab in fiddler to see the request, and copy the envelope tag in the request header.

It should look something like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><YourMethodName xmlns="http://yourserver.com/serviceName/v1.0"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

5.) Create a new request in Postman, and open the BODY tab, select the 'raw' radio button.

6.) Set content type drop down to 'XML'.

7.) Paste the envelope tag from above into the BODY field in Postman.

8.) Set the URL in Postman to whatever the request is being made in Fiddler, it will be 
the first line in the request in Fiddler, something like http://server/yourservice.svc

9.) Change the request type in Postman to POST

10.) Switch to the HEADERS tab in Postman, add a CONTENT-TYPE header, with a value of 'text/html'

11.) In the Fiddler request , you will see a SOAPAction header, copy the URL in this header

12.) In the HEADERS tab in Postman, add a 'SOAPAction' header, and paste the URL header into this value.

13.) Run your service!

**Bonus**

If you want to call a remote WCF service from Postman (that you can't run locally), debug your local project, so the WCF Test Client opens.

1.) Right-click on the 'My Service Projects' tree node in WCF Test Client, and click 'Add Service'.

2.) Enter your service URL

3.) Invoke a method on it as you would have done a local service, then track in Fiddler and add to Postman as per the steps above.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work because Fiddler doesn't capture localhost traffic. If I try the workarounds such as using my machine name, the WCF Test Client can't import my WCF service. (Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://tehql-004461:44394/ContractorCommunicationService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address...)

Answer (score 0):

From wcftestlient:

1. Copy the XML from the XML tab to postman's body/row with type XML.
   Make sure to remove the headers from the body.
2. Add soapaction to the header tab with SOAP action name.